# ArcGIS Online Nonspatial Data

Tags: arcgis-online, table, relates

How is nonspatial data managed in ArcGIS Online? If I have a table that is not part of a join or relate, but standalone, can I edit it on a map? In collector? Through REST? It appears the only way to add the data is by adding an item to the content (not publishing through ArcMap) and the only way to edit the data is through the Item Details "Data" tab.

What if I have two non-spatial tables related to each other, is there any way to depict this in AGOL? Can I edit the related data like I would a spatial dataset? In AGOL? In Collector? Through REST?

For this particular scenario, there is no AGS

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  The nine question marks here are a red flag that a much simpler question could be posed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing table data in ArcGIS Online can only happen through the Item Details > Data tab.

Web AppBuilder supports editing related tables.
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-edit.htm

Collector as well supports editing related tables as well. Both WAB and Collector can only access the tables through a feature on the map.

Comment: Russ, I see you work with Esri. Do you know if there are plans to add increased capabilities and support for nonspatial data in AGOL? Or for complex relationships? Like a feature layer with 1:M relates on multiple tables, or a feature related to a table related to another table, etc.

Comment: So we do have plans to bring that table experience from the data tab into the map viewer, this is aimed for the end of this year. This supports multi level relationships and will allow data editing.